# Unable to copy a file with '$' in name in Linux

Tags: linux

Inside of my Linux directory, I have a file named `TopSample$Config.class`. 
 Whenever I try to copy this file to another location/directory, it is not allowing me to do so.

I am doing it this way:

```
cp TopSample$Config.class /home/praveen/com/config/
```

Please let me know if this isn't possible.

Comment: Quote the $: `TopSample\$etc`, or `'TopSample$etc'`. And avoid using filenames with dollarsigns, spaces, &, |, > etc. on linux.

Comment: @alexis: Java compilers create these files without you asking for it. Besides, all tools should be able to handle funny characters in filenames.

Comment: I see. The tools can certainly handle them, beginners to the commandline are another story.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The shell will interpret `$Config` as a variable. And it will expand to empty string.
You can put single quotes around to keep the literal value:

```
cp 'TopSample$Config.class' /home/praveen/com/config/
```

Another way is to escape the `$`(dollar sign) by using `\`(backslash)

```
cp TopSample\$Config.class /home/praveen/com/config/
```

Answer (score 2):

Put single quotes around the filename.

```
cp 'TopSample$Config.class' /home/praveen/com/config
```

Answer (score 1):

Or replace the offending character with the filename metacharacter of '?', meaning "any one character".  Note that while this might be more convenient and requires the fewest keystrokes, be aware that a filename of `TopSample?Config.class` will also match `TopSampleaConfig.class`, `TopSamplebConfig.class`, `TopSamplecConfig.class`, etc.