# Using dollar sign in sqlplus spool file

Tags: oracle, unix, sqlplus

How to use file name with dollar sign (ie, '$') in unix like below

```
SQL> spool DIR$work.sql
SP2-0332: Cannot create spool file.
```

and i tried like below

```
SQL> spool DIR\$work.sql
SP2-0332: Cannot create spool file.
SQL> spool 'DIR\$work.sql'
SP2-0332: Cannot create spool file.
SQL> spool 'DIR$work.sql'
SP2-0332: Cannot create spool file.
```

I couldn't succeed in any way to create such file in oracle.
I have oracle 11g version.

In windows sqlplus it works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668142/linux-unable-to-copy-a-file-containing-dollar-symbol-as-part-of-name

Comment: @UltraCommit It works externally when i do `cat` or `touch` commands, but not in spool command in sqlplus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`set escchar`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG161) setting to stop Oracle interpreting the dollar sign:

```
SQL> show escchar
escchar OFF
SQL> spool /tmp/$work.sql
SP2-0332: Cannot create spool file.
SQL> set escchar $
SQL> spool /tmp/$work.sql
SQL>
```

You are now spooling to that file name.

```
SQL> select * from dual;

D
-
X

1 row selected.

SQL> spool off
SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
...

$ cat /tmp/\$work.sql
SQL> select * from dual;

D
-
X

1 row selected.

SQL> spool off
```

Also see My Oracle Support document 761384.1 for more information.