# Weird character encoding in filename: '$'\302\202''

Tags: encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, filenames

I received a file with the name **E Poste '$'\302\202''lectrique.csv** (from `ls -l` on my linux).

The **'$'\302\202''** part means the French accented letter "e" with acute ("é"). The file is automatically generated from an old system, so there is nothing we can do on that part :/

- **'$'\302\202''** is é
- **'$'\302\207''** is ç
- **'$'\302\203''** is à

A lot of apps (intellij, eclipse, etc) don't know what this character is and just skip it.

I would like to know how I can convert the filename to ISO/UTF-8/etc... something human readable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to copy a file with '$' in name in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668142/unable-to-copy-a-file-with-in-name-in-linux)